# DynamoDB - problems using a local installation

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Am attempting to work with a local install of DynamoDb (per [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html)). Ive opened the web UI (`http://localhost:8000/shell`) and created a few tables and can see them using the web UI.

If I try to view these same tables using either the cmd line or a simple java app I don't see them.

Cmd line: `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

Java:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient().withEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");

public void listMyTables() {
    TableCollection<ListTablesResult> tables = dynamoDB.listTables();
    Iterator<Table> iterator = tables.iterator();

    System.out.println("Listing table names");

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Table table = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(table.getTableName());
    }
}
```

I've tried adding my credentials as follows:

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(
        new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("credentials")).withEndpoint("http://localhost:8000"));
```

To further confuse matters: if I create a table using the cmdline I can see it appear using the above cmdline but not via the WebUI or Java.

So: what glaringly obvious error am I making?

---

### Addendum:

Im pretty sure all three methods are looking at the local db because if I stop it they all error out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. If you start the local db instance as follows:

> java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar **-sharedDb**

it works between the UI, cmd line and Java. Note the `-sharedDb` part of the cmd line. I believe that the local shell starts up in a "region" and unless you specify the region with your commands (or use the above param to negate regions) you'll run into what I saw above.